# Is there a convenient way to create formatted output with style in JSF?

Tags: jsf

I have a JSF bases web application where i use `h:outputFormat` and `f:param` to inject parameter values in a localized string literal.

This is my JSF:

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{msg['camelComplaint']}">
    <f:param value="#{crusadeBean.camelCount}" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

This is my message:

```
camelComplaint=Sallah, I said no camels. That's {0} camels. Can't you count?
```

And this is the generated output:

```html
Sallah, I said no camels. That's 5 camels. Can't you count?
```

This is all fine and as expected. I'd like, however, to highlight the injected parameter value. That is, I'd like to create the following output:

```html
Sallah, I said no camels. That's <span class="ui-highlight">5</span> camels. Can't you count?
```

*Is there a convenient way to style individual parameters?*

This is what I've tried so far:

1. Splitting the string literal into multiple parts and using multiple `h:outputText`:

   ```
   <h:outputText value="#{msg['camelComplaint.part0']} " />
   <h:outputText value="#{crusadeBean.camelCount}" styleClass="ui-highlight" />
   <h:outputText value=" #{msg['camelComplaint.part1']}" />
   ```

   With:

   ```
   camelComplaint.part0=Sallah, I said no camels. That's
   camelComplaint.part1=camels. Can't you count?
   ```

   While this creates the desired output, it will fail, if the order of some parameters needs to be switched in the localization. It also requires part of the literals (the spaces surrounding the parameter value) to be in JSF and is, arguably, a rather ugly solution.
2. Adding raw HTML to the Parameter value:

   ```
   <h:outputFormat value="#{msg['camelComplaint']}" escape="false">
       <f:param value="&lt;span class=&quot;ui-highlight&quot;&gt;#{crusadeBean.camelCount}&lt;/span&gt;" />
   </h:outputFormat>
   ```

   This, again, creates the desired output, but depends on the usage of `escape="false"`. That means that this solution may break, if the parameter value contains certain characters (such as `<` or `>`) or is outright dangerous, if the parameter value is user-generated content (as it would allow code injection). The code is also not very readable.
3. Adding raw HTML to the string literal:

   ```
   <h:outputFormat value="#{msg['camelComplaint']}" escape="false">
       <f:param value="#{crusadeBean.camelCount}" />
   </h:outputFormat>
   ```

   With:

   ```
   camelComplaint=Sallah, I said no camels. That's <span style="ui-highlight">{0}</span> camels. Can't you count?
   ```

   This, again, creates the desired output, but also depends on the usage of `escape="false"` and therefore suffers from the same problems as the previous solution. Additionally, it moves part of the layout into the localization.

Comment: @Kukeltje I've already looked at omnifaces, but it didn't occur to me to look further then `o:outputFormat`, but`o:param` seems interesting. I've just put a `h:outputText` inside a `o:param` and, so far, it seems to be doing what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jaw-dropping [OmniFaces](http://www.omnifaces.org) comes to the rescue here (as in many other places). It's [`o:param`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/param) replacement of `f:param`, accepts content children as well, next to using a `value` attribute. So assuming your original localization:

```
camelComplaint=Sallah, I said no camels. That's {0} camels. Can't you count?
```

And using a mix of your original code, solution two, and using the `o:param`, the following will work

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{msg['camelComplaint']}" escape="false">
    <o:param>
        <span class="ui-highlight">
            <h:outputText value="#{crusadeBean.camelCount}" />
        </span>
    </o:param>
</h:outputFormat>
```

And if you just need a style, you can, as you yourself rightfully corrected me, use a `styleClass` on the `h:outputText`

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{msg['camelComplaint']}" escape="false">
    <o:param>
        <h:outputText value="#{crusadeBean.camelCount}" styleClass="ui-highlight" />
    </o:param>
</h:outputFormat>
```

The outputText has no `escape="false"` so it will escape all things! The outputFormat has none so I'd assume it accepts the plain html and renders it as such

And you could wrap this easily in a composite component and do

```
<my:localizationHighlightFormat message="#{msg['camelComplaint']}" value="#{msg['camelComplaint']}" />
```

Comment: `<h:outputText value="#{crusadeBean.camelCount}" styleClass="ui-highlight" />` will make it even more concise.

Comment: And did you actually mean `f:param` and not `o:param`? I think only the letter works.

Comment: I've just checked both variants, and only `o:param` will do. OmniFaces doesn't stop to amaze me.

Comment: updated the answer, will remove all now superfluous comments. Thanks btw for the quick feedback... Much appreciated.

Comment: That's a nice one. Going to remember that :-)